# Classify music to genre with WEKA

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, nearest-neighbor

I am struggling to actually implement the classifying part of my investigations into the possibility of classifying music according to some features of music files.

What I have currently produced is code that reads a table of features from the DB and then puts it back into the DB in another table.

The problem is that I do not know how to work with the instances type. Documentation is crap - I have no clue what to do.

What I want to do: I want to use a given set of music files and compute their feature vectors. After this data has been put into arff, I would manually join it with genre data (the gial i.e.). and then save it into a MySQL table.

AFAIU the chain should be like this:

- Read from DB
- Somehow train a K-nearest neighbor classifier on a set of the features (related to genre)  per music file for a body of 10 files.
- Use this to classify a set of files with the same features but unknown genre.
- Somehow output results so that they can be machine-readable in the database.

I have found no examples of the output of the data actually being used for further processing so I cannot further haggle :/

After this has been done, I would like to read it back and conduct a classification on a new body of music (the features I have computed by music or using a sample file set). The results should be put back into the DB in yet another new table, detailing what file has which category (assigned).

Here is my code:

```
package org.tuhh.cpmgg.weka;

import weka.core.*;
import weka.core.converters.*;
import weka.experiment.InstanceQuery;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; 

@Path("/weka2")
public class weka_chain {

  /**
   * loads a dataset from mysql db
   * @param args the commandline arguments
   */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String main() 
            throws Exception {

    java.util.List resultList;

    /*Gets data from DB*/

    InstanceQuery query = new InstanceQuery();
    query.setDatabaseURL("jdbc:mysql://127.2.73.130:3306/cpmgg");
    query.setUsername("adminnNWqHkW");
    query.setPassword("zLlkWsd-NsnQ");
    query.setQuery("SELECT * FROM features"); //Read table
    Instances data = query.retrieveInstances(); //into data
    data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1); //sets the number of classes (creates index)

    /*Classifiers */

    String algorithm = "weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes"; // Sets the type of classifier (many available)

    resultList = new ArrayList();

    Weka1 weka; 
    try {
        weka = new Weka1(algorithm, "lol");
        resultList = weka.weka(algorithm, data); //Essentially what is happening



        /* TODO:
         * Define Output so that it is in table form/instance form
         * This means creating output using the old applet and somehow (?) distilling it into table shape
         */


    /* Saves Results to DB */

    DatabaseSaver save = new DatabaseSaver();
    // save.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weka_test");
    save.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.2.73.130:3306/cpmgg");
    //save.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate");
    save.setUser("AMDINADMIN");
    save.setPassword("PASS_ PASS");
    save.setInstances(data); // define outputtype
    save.setRelationForTableName(false);
    save.setTableName("weka_rslts");
    save.connectToDatabase();
    save.writeBatch();

    return "done";
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on OpenShift?  I don't see anything specific in your question about it.

Comment: Yes, I run this on OpenShift but due to building errors (build fails for other parts of the project so it stops dead in its tracks for all other parts) I have resorted to running it locally.

Comment: ** Additional Info **

Answer (score 0):

There is a very interesting Weka tutorial that answers some parts of your questions.

The steps are:

1. Feature extraction using jAudio tutorial
2. Change the output file format to ARFF
3. Change the sample rate to match the audio files
4. Change the features calculating scheme Then by loading the dataset on Weka you have the
   opportunity to use a classifier to classify the genres of each track.

Check out the following link: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~music/cmsip/projects/p6.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Emusic/cmsip/projects/p6.pdf)